# JPQL CASE STATEMENT in WHERE CLAUSE PROBLEMS

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have some problems with case statement in `where` clause. If someone knows how to fix this please help me! Thank you.

```
 @Query("select e from EventTeamPlayer etp "
                + "join etp.event e "
                + "left join e.leagueTournament lt "
                + "left join lt.sportCategory sc "
                + "left join e.sport s "
                + "left join etp.homeTeamPlayer htpl "
                + "left join etp.awayTeamPlayer atpl "
                + "left join lt.country c "
                + "left join e.eventStatus es "
                + "where (e.startDate >= :startDate and e.startDate <= :endDate) "
                + "and lt.id = :leagueTournamentId "
                + "and (lt.defaultName like :searchTerm or "
                     + "s.name like :searchTerm or "
                     + "htpl.name like :searchTerm or "
                     + "atpl.name like :searchTerm or "
                     + "e.id like :searchTerm) and "
                     + "(case when (:minDate is not null and :maxDate is not null) "
                     + " then (e.startDate >=:minDate and e.startDate<=:maxDate)   else true end) = true")
    Page<Event> getEventsForWebAdmin(Pageable pageable, 
                                     @Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, 
                                     @Param("leagueTournamentId") int leagueTournamentId, 
                                     @Param("startDate") Date startDate, 
                                     @Param("endDate") Date endDate,
                                     @Param("minDate") Date minDate,
                                     @Param("maxDate") Date maxDate);
```

AND HERE IS THE ERROR IN LOG :

> **Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   unexpected AST node: and near line 1, column 589** [select e from
>   com.itengine.bettinggateway.dao.EventTeamPlayer etp join etp.event e
>   left join e.leagueTournament lt left join lt.sportCategory sc left
>   join e.sport s left join etp.homeTeamPlayer htpl left join
>   etp.awayTeamPlayer atpl left join lt.country c left join e.eventStatus
>   es where (e.startDate >= :startDate and e.startDate <= :endDate) and
>   (lt.defaultName like :searchTerm or s.name like :searchTerm or
>   htpl.name like :searchTerm or atpl.name like :searchTerm or e.id like
>   :searchTerm) and (case when (:minDate is not null and :maxDate is not
>   null)  then (e.startDate >=:minDate and e.startDate<=:maxDate) else
>   true end) = true and lt.id = :leagueTournamentId]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont think you can pull that kind of statement in JPQL.

Try to replace it with something like this:

```
AND
(
   (:minDate is not null and :maxDate is not null
         and e.startDate >=:minDate and e.startDate<=:maxDate)
   OR
   (:minDate is null or :maxDate is  null)                   
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [JPQL API docs](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.2/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions), it says that:

`when_clause::= WHEN conditional_expression THEN scalar_expression`

So `then` clause can use:

`scalar_expression ::= arithmetic_expression | string_primary | enum_primary | datetime_primary | boolean_primary | case_expression | entity_type_expression`

And you are violating this within your then clause. Try to replace your CASE with AND-OR combination.